# In python, make a tempfile in the same directory as another file?

Tags: python, file, temporary-files

I need to update a file.  I read it in and write it out with changes. However, I'd prefer to write to a temporary file and rename it into place.

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tempname = temp.name
temp.write(new_data)
temp.close()
os.rename(tempname, data_file_name)
```

The problem is that `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` makes the temporary file in `/tmp` which is a different file system.  This means `os.rename()` fails.  If I use `shlib.move()` instead then I don't have the atomic update that `mv` provides (for files in the same file system, yadda, yadda, etc.)

I know `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` takes a `dir` parameter, but `data_file_name` might be `"foo.txt"` in which case `dir='.'`; or `data_file_name` might be `"/path/to/the/data/foo.txt"` in which case `dir="/path/to/the/data"`.

What I'd really like is the temp file to be `data_file_name + "some random data"`. This would have the benefit of failing in a way that would leave behind useful clues.

Suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using a temporary file in the first place, if you don't want it to be put in the directory for temporary files? What speaks against using ordinary files?

Comment: David: I want to use a temporary file because I want the update to be atomic (or as atomic as one can be with os.rename()). That is, if the file system fills or there is some other problem, I don't want the file to be half-written.

Comment: Well, this might be difficult to achieve, since you never really know, if files written to a different folder are on the same file system as your local directory. I see the advantage of organizing your output in some kind of commit. To be relatively sure that this is the case, I would probably manage my own temporary directory -- although you would then care for the cleanup of this folder as well.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use:

- `prefix` to make the temporary file begin with the same name as the
  original file.
- `dir` to specify where to place the temporary file.
- `os.path.split` to split the directory from the filename.

---

```
import tempfile
import os
dirname, basename = os.path.split(filename)
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=basename, dir=dirname)
print(temp.name)
```

Comment: If filename = 'foo' then dirname will be ''.  I'm pleasantly surprised that NamedTemporaryFile works with dir='' the same as dir=None. Thanks!

Comment: Just to make this explicit: You must also pass `delete=False` to the NamedTemporaryFile constructor, or the file will be deleted on close.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a file location in 'dir' constructor parameter.
It works, as you wish.

```
>>> t = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir="/Users/rafal")
>>> t.name
'/Users/rafal/tmplo45Js'
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile

Comment: info: without `delete=False` the file is deleted as soon as the file handler is closed.

Comment: This assumes we know what the dir is.

Comment: We know that. OP's already question contains splitting a path into dir and file name, so that it's redundant to write about it here.

Answer (score 5):

To meet all your checklist I think you'd want to use...

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=data_file_name, dir=path,
                                   delete=False)
```

Important to have the `delete=False`, because otherwise:

> [...] If delete is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is
>   closed.

Comment: This assumes we know what the path is.

Answer (score 2):

I use the current time as "some random data" appended to a base string for a unique temporary filename:

```
import time

temp_file_name = data_file_name + str(time.time())
```

Comment: This is tempting, but I've seen enough security issues from people rolling their own temp file system that I know to use the one that tempfile provides.

Comment: Just as an added note here, a few years later, this will have conflicts if this runs twice in the same millisecond, which is definitely possible in most people's use cases. It's better just to use the official implementation of tempfile, to stuff like that, and race conditions when you try to avoid it.

Comment: And if you run your code with many parallel instances (why else would you need a unique filename?) the clash is almost guaranteed... In a distributed massive-parallel system I ended up having a combination of hostname, process-ID, and time...

Answer (score -1):

The `tempfile` module that you use provides a secure way of managing temporary files. If you really want to use your own system, you should just be aware that it could be vulnerable to attacks (particularly symlink attacks).

A simple way to generate a temporary unique filename (albeit a rather long name) is:

```
import uuid
import os

tempfilename = 'myprefix-%s.dat' % str(uuid.uuid4())

with open(tempfilename, 'rw') as tempfile:
    # do stuff

os.remove(tempfilename)
```

But this is a bit hackish; really rather consider using the `tempfile` module with the correct `prefix` and `dir` parameters passed to `NamedTemporaryFile`, as described in the other answers.

Comment: This is tempting, but I've seen enough security issues caused by people rolling their own temp file system that I know to use the one that tempfile provides.

Comment: Absolutely, using something like this is a bad idea in production code. In an environment where this isn't a concern (e.g. logging of simulation data), `uuid` presents a way of generating a unique random string.